# Missing partial comments/_comment in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using a tutorial to get a feel for ruby, I am very much a beginner. Before posting this I have spent a couple of hours trying to resolve this myself with no luck. Sorry in advance if my explanation isn't great:

So I am getting this error screen:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfT2u.png)

I am following a tutorial to make a basic reddit style app and I am trying to add the comments functionality.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] for information on how to revise your post so that we are best able to assist you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you render a collection like `render @comments`, Rails will check the type name of the items in `@comments` (i.e. 'comment') then look for a partial under `app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb` by default (note the plural singular distinction between the partial name and the folder/collection name).

The following steps should resolve your issue:

**Create a comments partial under:**

`app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb`

Now, when you call `render @comments`, each item of your collection is passed to the partial as a local variable as the same name without the underscore:

**In _comment.html.erb**

```
<%# comment is defined because it matches the name of the partial %>
<%= comment.<some_attribute_on_comment> %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I made a spelling mistake in the comments partial folder "_comments.html.erb" instead of "_comment.html.erb"